# PhoneGap Android Plugin issue trying to setContentView

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to get my first Android plugin to work.  I've successfully registered it and able to execute it.  Inside of my plugin execute action, I am trying to do the following:

```
ctx.setContentView(R.layout.map);
```

Which contains a new layout to load google maps; however, when I run this I receive the following error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Any idea how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run it on UI thread. You can touch UI elements only on UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(runb);

private Runnable runb = new Runnable() {

     public void run(){
           //call setContentView code here. 
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on that and provide an example to set the content view like I'm trying to do?

Comment: After trying that the application crashes due to an unexpected error.

Comment: well, the problem you stated belongs to running on the UI thread, that is how you resolve in native code. runonUIthread works on context.